# Is there a way to check to which scientific journals a specific library has access?

Tags: publications, publishers, library

Is there a way to check which journals are available in a specific library/university? For example, my university library has access to some, but not all, the scientific journals related to Machine Learning in Springer. It would be helpful in case I need to move in order to get access to a specific topic or group of related papers.

Comment: Ask the librarian?

Comment: Might work for university libraries, but in the public ones the answers usually don´t go further than the name of the publisher..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you (marsop) wrote *Austria* as place of residence in your profile, you may be interested in the **[EZB database](http://rzblx1.uni-regensburg.de/ezeit/index.phtml?bibid=AAAAA&colors=7&lang=en)** that lists university library **electronic journal subscriptions** for most institutions in 5 countries (Austria, Czech Republic, Germany, Slovakia, Switzerland) and a few others (including the Library of Congress in Washington, DC). It also supplies information for many non-university libraries that typically have electronic journal subscriptions.

To use it, first click on "Choose Institution" on the left side of the page. Then select your institution (if it is listed). If you then search for journals, you will see a color code next to the journal names indicating whether members of the institution have (electronic) access to the journal's content.

Comment: The EZB is incredibly useful, and if it's only to figure out which friend to mail for having an article downloaded... Maybe you can mention the countries it's covering, so that others can judge whether it might be useful for them?

Comment: This is exactly what I was searching for, thanks.

Answer (score 7):

These come to my mind:

1. The best way is to ask the librarian to give you a list of journals available in their library.
2. Check the website of the library/ university you are interested to study in, they may list the journals and publications which they have access to.
3. *Very few* journals/ publishers list the libraries/ research institutes where their journals are available in.
4. Also, you may email the journal and ask their customers service whether they are available in a specific library or not. I have never tried this and I am not sure whether they are going to answer you.

Comment: I would precede this with "0. Check the library catalogue", but 1 is a good followup (most libraries will have this to hand). The catalogue will almost always list every subscribed title, but won't always include all the "extras" from a Big Deal type subscription.